# ListBox inside Datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms

Can we bring a listbox inside a datagridview in C# Winforms. If yes , plsease suggest as to how to bind the values?

Appreciate if ppls could help me in this.

Comment: What's your goal? Do you want to edit value by selecting  from a list in a cell? or Do you want to only show a list of values in a cell? Showing a `ListBox` in a `DataGridView` doesn't seem to be such useful.

Comment: An alternative to `DataGridView` is `TableLayoutPanel` if you just want rows and columns. You can put practically anything in a `TableLayoutPanel` cell, including a `ListBox` or another `TableLayoutPanel`. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel%28v=vs.110%29.aspx.